# QT Application --- WIFI connection

Tags: c++, qt, wifi, qt4

Does QT have any APIs for detecting wireless networks?  If not, are there any other cross-platform means of detecting wireless networks?

Comment: The question is justified. It is not a ambiguous, vage or incomplete question as I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt has no wifi support out of the box, wifi is too platform-specific. Use native API's for working with wifi.

Answer (score 1):

[QNetworkInterface](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkinterface.html) is the closest class, AFAICT, but as Raiv says, Qt does not support Wifi-network detection.

You can build the GUI & controlling logic with Qt, but you must look elsewhere for a cross-platform wifi library (if any exist, otherwise you have to write your own for every platform you want to support).